# Bitcore full node list with Wallet service enabled?

Tags: spv, bitcore

Is there any Bitcore full node list out there? I wanted that in order to use the Wallet Service while not being dependant on only one server.

**edit:** [quote](https://bitcore.io/guides/wallet-service/) on their website:

> You should now be able to run your own Wallet Service for your users.
>   Now you can have ultimate control over your wallets **without trusting
>   random SPV nodes on the Internet**.

I want just the opposite. If it's possible I want a *very* long list of bitcore nodes.

**edit2: (from comments)**

I know bitcore is based on bitcoin core. but I want to know if there's a directory for bitcore nodes running wallet service. nodes can discover each other through p2p protocol but afaik they don't specify, in the bitcore case, which services they are running.

Like the directories for nodes running Electrum protocol. It would be awesome.

Answer (score 3):

**Nodes don't provide wallet services** (like Bitpays Bitcore [don't mix that up with Bitcoin Core]). The only service they provide is SPV transaction filtering (which is much "slower").

Running your own wallet service (like BitPays Bitcore) can be useful if you have your own setup, etc. (It's more a server/client thing).

Bitcore is basically a Bitcoin Core full node with some extra database layers (address index, etc.).
The full node behind Bitcore will connect to some dozens other full nodes (p2p).

You don't want to manually maintain a list of full nodes. There is a built in p2p address manager.

Comment: At the bitcore wallet service docs (https://bitcore.io/guides/wallet-service/) states that you can add wallet service addon to a **full node**, and that seems a requirement. Copay wallet and other clients lets you specify your own full-node-with-wallet-service url,  that's why I thought there may exist a directory for nodes running the wallet service, and for every install the default server is the same.

Comment: I know bitcore is based on bitcoin core. but i want to know if there's a directory for bitcore nodes running wallet service. nodes can discover each other through p2p protocol but afaik they don't specify ,in the bitcore case, which services they are running.